# Deprecated Functionality: Optional parameter $cart_id declared before required parameter $storeId is implicitly treated as a required

Tags: magento

i am new to Magento, while installing i am getting this error

Deprecated Functionality: Optional parameter $cart_id declared before required parameter $storeId is implicitly treated as a required parameter in C:\x   ampp\htdocs\e-commerce\app\code\Gaggle\PaypalApi\Model\SetPaymentMethodOnCartManagement.php on line 87

i tried with all command but nothing happend

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJim3.png)

Comment: This error relate compatible with php8.2, I guest you are using Magento version 2.4.6. You need to declare variable $cart_id in class SetPaymentMethodOnCartManagement.php to fix this error. If you don't know about code, can you update your code in that file and then I can fix code for you.